Why Strapi cms 'Open the administration' button is missing on production? Is it a feature?
Strapi development mode gives 'Open the administration' button on start screen i.e
https://cms.abc.com

But not on production enviromnent. Is it a feature? If so its so annoying to put '/admin' everytime admin wants to access cms. Can we enable the button on production enviroment as well?

There should be the button in all environments.

Maybe there is a delta between production and not production users rights/roles. Did you take a look at https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-s-user-roles-and-permissions-for-admin-panel-1 ?
